# None background of a plot

Tags: plotting

When we use `Background-> None` in plot options, and export the plot for example as a `PNG` format, but we have a plot with a white background when we insert in a software as Powerpoint. How can we export a plot without any background?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the option `Background->None` in your [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export) call:

```
file = Export["tst1.png", Graphics[Circle[]], "PNG", Background->None];

Style[Import[file], Background->LightBlue]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
myfig = RemoveBackground[Graphics[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]]];

Export["/.../myfig.png", myfig, "PNG"]
```

Comment: FWIW: this works with Mathematica 11.0 on a Mac running Mojave. @b3m2a1 's answer, unfortunately, still produces a white background.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way I tend to do it:

```
Export[
 "path/to/file/asd.png",
 Rasterize[
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10},
     Background -> None
     ],
  Background -> None
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: I think this cannot work!!

Comment: @Irreversible If it can't that's news to me. It works on my Mac.